# Ember.js create a child controller without route

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to create a child controller to limit the number of articles to be retrieved. The idea is to have something like that:

```
var HomeSectionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  selectedArticles: functioin(){
    // code here
  }.property('articles')
});
```

First real project using Ember and Ember-CLI so I'm still digesting the concepts.

This is how things are looking so far:

models/home.js

```
var Home = DS.Model.extend({
  sections: DS.hasMany('homeSection', {async: true})
});

Home.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: 1,
      sections: [1, 2]
    }
  ]
});

export default Home;
```

models/home-section.js

```
var HomeSection = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});

HomeSection.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {id: 1, title: 'About', articles: [1,2,3,4,5]},
    {id: 2, title: 'Contact'}
  ]
});

export default HomeSection;
```

models/home-article.js

```
var HomeArticle = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});

HomeArticle.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {id: 1, title: 'Article 1'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Article 2'},
    {id: 3, title: 'Article 3'},
    {id: 4, title: 'Article 4'},
    {id: 5, title: 'Article 5'},
  ]
});

export default HomeArticle;
```

routes/home.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('home');
  }
});
```

templates/home.hbs

```
{{partial "home/sections"}}
```

template/home/sections.hbs

```
{{#each model}}
<div class="sections">
  {{#each sections}}
    {{#each articles}}
     ... the magic happens here!
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Where do I create the `HomeSectionController`. Is the `controllers/home-section.js` the right naming structure?

Many Thanks,

H

***UPDATE:***

My doubt was about child controllers without routes, not really related with ember-cli. Anyway, I have found a good discussion here http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/parent-child-controller-relationships-without-using-routes/761/19 answering some of the questions I had before.